# Email receive after one day in drupal 6

Tags: 6, emails

I am using  [SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/SMTP) module to send mail. Email sends but receives after one day. I am unable to identify what is the issue.

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Thank :)

Comment: Also I have check my firewall setting.

Comment: if its like drupal 7, e-mails get sent after a cron run. How often is your cron running?